# Where can I register unit of work service in .NET 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-6.0

I wonder how I can register unitofwork service in .NET 6.

In previous versions of .NET Core, it was possible to register a unitofwork service in startup.cs file as below.

```
services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
```

In .NET 6, startup.cs and program.cs files are merged.

Is it possible to register the service in program.cs? If possible, then how?

Comment: Could you provide a code that demonstrates how you did it in previous versions?

Comment: I added the sample line in question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Let's begin with your questions

***`"Is it possible to register the service in program.cs?"`***

> Yes its Absolutely possible to register `service` in `program.cs`.

***`"If possible, then how?"`***

> Here is the `Program.cs` example for you on `asp.net 6`:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
```

> ***`Note:`***
>
> It’s almost similar to `asp.net core 3.2` or `asp.net 5` which we used
> to do in startup.cs file. Same thing need to do in [`asp.net 6 program.cs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60-samples?view=aspnetcore-6.0#aspnet-core-6-3) file just a bit different way.

***If you need full example on `asp.net 6` You can then check below details answer:***

***`Model:`***

I would use `User` model to build `UnitOfWork` in `dotnet 6` sample

```
public class User
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

***`ApplicationDbContext:`***

```
public class ApplicationDbContext: DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            //  base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("User");
        }
       
    }
```

> ***Note:***
>
> You should similar `SQL Table` on your database, to make is easier here I am
> providing the Database script as well.

***`SQL Script:`***

```
CREATE TABLE [User]
(
    Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY default NEWID(),
    [FirstName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Email] [varchar](50) NULL,
 
)
INSERT INTO [User] ([FirstName], [LastName], [Email])
VALUES ( 'FirstTestName', 'FirstLastName', 'testemail.@outlook.com');
```

***`IGenericRepository:`***

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        Task<IEnumerable<T>> All();
        Task<T> GetById(Guid id);
        Task<bool> Add(T entity);
        Task<bool> Delete(Guid id);
        Task<bool> Upsert(T entity);
        Task<IEnumerable<T>> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    }
```

***`GenericRepository:`***

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        protected ApplicationDbContext context;
        internal DbSet<T> dbSet;
        public readonly ILogger _logger;

        public GenericRepository(
            ApplicationDbContext context,
            ILogger logger)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.dbSet = context.Set<T>();
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public virtual async Task<T> GetById(Guid id)
        {
            return await dbSet.FindAsync(id);
        }

        public virtual async Task<bool> Add(T entity)
        {
            await dbSet.AddAsync(entity);
            return true;
        }

        public virtual Task<bool> Delete(Guid id)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public virtual Task<IEnumerable<T>> All()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return await dbSet.Where(predicate).ToListAsync();
        }

        public virtual Task<bool> Upsert(T entity)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

***`IUnitOfWork:`***

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
    {
        IUserRepository Users { get; }

        Task CompleteAsync();
    }
```

***`UnitOfWork:`***

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public IUserRepository Users { get; private set; }

        public UnitOfWork(ApplicationDbContext context, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _context = context;
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("logs");

            Users = new UserRepository(context, _logger);
        }
        
        public async Task CompleteAsync()
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _context.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

***`UserRepository:`***

```
    public class UserRepository : GenericRepository<User>, IUserRepository
    {
        public UserRepository(ApplicationDbContext context, ILogger logger) : base(context, logger) { }

        public override async Task<IEnumerable<User>> All()
        {
            try
            {
                return await dbSet.ToListAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "{Repo} All function error", typeof(UserRepository));
                return new List<User>();
            }
        }
}
```

***`UnitOfWorkUsersController:`***

```
[ApiController]
public class UnitOfWorkUsersController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<UnitOfWorkUsersController> _logger;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public UnitOfWorkUsersController(
        ILogger<UnitOfWorkUsersController> logger,
        IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        var users = await _unitOfWork.Users.All();
        return Ok(users);
    }

}
```

***`Program.cs:`***

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

***`Output:`***

[image]

[image]

Hope above steps guided you accordingly. If you still need [`more details you can have a look our official document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60-samples?view=aspnetcore-6.0#aspnet-core-6-3)

Comment: Thanks for the response. But in the example you sent, I get null reference exception for DbSet property. in Generic Repository I searched for the proper solution but could not find out. What is the reason? Code is below.

            this.context = context;
            this.dbSet = context.Set<T>();
            _logger = logger;

Comment: Did you set `ApplicationDbContext` ? You should set `DbSet<User>` with the class you want to pass in `IUnitOfWork` interface. Anyway, I have updated that part also in solution.

Answer (score 1):

The new .Net 6 is a simplified version of the previous .Net 5.

You can do dependency injection within the `Program.cs` file in your project root directory.

Example:

You should have this line

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
```

If not already declared, create the following variable:

```
var app = builder.Build();
```

You can then interact with services by using "app.Services" property.

```
app.Services.GetServices(typeof(MyService));
```

Or you can use your own middleware

```
app.MyMiddleware();
```

Refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60-samples?view=aspnetcore-6.0) Microsoft Documentation page for migration examples.