# I'm building a web sales platform in ASP.NET Core MVC, what's the best way to structure the DbContext(s)?

Tags: security, asp.net-core-mvc, datacontext, asp.net-core-6.0

I have:

1. regular visitors
2. merchants
3. and of course our admins and internal team

Do I store all user accounts in the `[regular visitors]` database, then separate "sensitive" data into a `[merchants]` and an `[internal]` database to ensure at least some kind of security or is there a better alternative?

Also, I'm using Entity Framework to build the database - although I'm currently only working on the web interface, I eventually want to add a mobile app interface and possibly a windows app interface to the project - how do I ensure the models are shared so I don't have redundant code to duplicate?

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Thanks.

*Currently storing all data in a singular database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Let's clarify few things before starting, if you could observe now a days, all typical modern application handle request either from mobile device or web browser (all the platforms like Windows, Mac, Linux). and from the desktop platform.
> See the drawing below:

***`Application Architecture:`***

[image]

Therefore, the request are coming from different devices, which we call (cross platform) but we can make the endpoint universal. There are different technology out there. You could consider [`Asp.net Web API`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website&view=aspnetcore-6.0)

> Now come to your point.

***`"How do I ensure the models are shared so I don't have redundant code to duplicate?"`***

> There are couple of way to restrict code redundancy. You can consider
> [`SOLID principle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/may/csharp-best-practices-dangers-of-violating-solid-principles-in-csharp#the-single-responsibility-principle). Within the [`SOLID`](https://www.baeldung.com/solid-principles#s) you could specifically implement
> `Single Responsibility` means `a class should only have one responsibility` additionally you could implement [`Inheritance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/tutorials/inheritance#background-what-is-inheritance) of
> [`OOP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/tutorials/oop) so that you can reuse of the base code in your derive class
> when your `project/application` would continuously extended.

There are bundle of example you could found online for above terms.

> So what I am trying to explain is make your backend application
> universal so that it can handle all the request no matter where they
> are coming from. So that it would be easier for you to handle code
> reusability and eventually it would restrict the redundancy as well.

***`Now Consider Your Domain Model:`***

> Into your `ApplicationDbContext` you can now define all of your
> `domain model` like you can think of your business model as the domain
> model for example: `RegularVisitors`, `Merchants` and `admins and internal team` as `Users` domain model, You can design your
> `ApplicationDbContext` as below:

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext: DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Merchants> Merchants{ get; set; }
        public DbSet<RegularVisitors> RegularVisitors{ get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
           
            modelBuilder.Entity<Merchants>().ToTable("Merchants");
            modelBuilder.Entity<RegularVisitors>().ToTable("RegularVisitors");
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("User");
        }
       
    }
```

> This is how you could move forward considering your requirement. For
> details implementation you could consider [`this thread`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71244288/where-can-i-register-unit-of-work-service-in-net-6/71249103#71249103) to implement
> your requirement accordingly

Hope above steps and implementations guided you accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Farid. After reading more into Separation of Concerns (data and MVC-wise), this topic became uber level intimidating and even made me question whether MVC was right way to go!

Comment: Considering your current scenario from my dev experience I would say, Web API would a standard technology and Unit of work would be an ideal architecture and it will be great if you can implement SOLID concept.