# ASP.NET Core Web API What project type should i choose?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm confused what type of project should I use because I'm newbie to ASP.NET and programing as a whole.

I got instructions to create a web page to manage employees.

**The instructions** are:

- nav menu with 3 buttons
- 3 pages to show employees, positions, past employees
- editing, adding, removing and creating employees

The employees have to be on the server and the data have to be saved in a SQL database (there will be always just one client).

Technologies that I should use:

**Client**

- SASS, LESS or CSS (Bootstrap)
- Vue.js, VueCLI
- Typescript

**Server**

- ASP.NET Core Web API
- Docker container (Linux OS)
- Database: SQL

I tried to build the app in ASP.NET Core 5.0 using ASP.NET Core Web App but I'm not sure if its the correct project type because the server technology in the instructions is ASP.NET Core Web API.

In the instructions I got to study ASP.NET Web API 2 but there are just examples of web api project without interface.

I feel really lost in what should I do. I deleted the project several times because of confusion.

Can please someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: WebAPI project template then set up vuejs project which has nothing to do with asp.net as your Vue project will call your API. You should be able to find examples of calling API from vuejs from Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***`"I'm confused what type of project should I use because I'm newbie to ASP.NET and programing as a whole?"`***

> Based on your description and requirement you should have one
> `client-side (frontend) project` and one `server-side (backend project)` within the same solution. You could follow the steps below.

**`Client: Frondtend Project:`**

> For `client-side vue.js` project you could take the project like
> below. Please see the screen shot.

[image]

> **Note:** For more details steps you could check our [`official document here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-vue?view=vs-2022)

**`Server: Backend Project:`**

> For dealing with `client-side` vue.js request you should have one
> `server-side backend project` which should be kind of `asp.net core web API` project. You could take this like below.

[image]

> **Note:** For more details steps you could check our [`official document here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-vue?view=vs-2022)

**`Project Request Architecture:`**

> Your `vue.js` `client-side` which we call `front-end` application will
> sent request to your `asp.net core web API` application `controller`.
> For example your `employees controller` then you should return
> required data from your `controller` which you will bind to your
> `client-side` project eventually. Your project architecture should look like below:

[image]

> For details you could check [`official document here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website&view=aspnetcore-5.0)

**`Your Domain Class:`**

Based on your description you should have `employee domain class` for exaple an imaginary `employee class` like below:

```cs
public class Employee 
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

***`ApplicationDbContext:`***

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext: DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Employee> Employee { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            //  base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().ToTable("Employee");
        }
       
    }
```

> ***Note:***
>
> You should similar `SQL Table` on your database, to make is easier here I am
> providing the Database script as well.

***`SQL Script:`***

```cs
CREATE TABLE [Employee]
(
    Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY default NEWID(),
    [FirstName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Email] [varchar](50) NULL,
 
)
```

***`Controller:`***

```cs
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UnitOfWorkEmployeeController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<UnitOfWorkEmployeeController> _logger;
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

        public UnitOfWorkEmployeeController(
            ILogger<UnitOfWorkEmployeeController> logger,
            IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
        {

            var employees = await _unitOfWork.Employee.All();
            return Ok(employees);
        }
        
    }
}
```

> **Note:** If you need more details steps reagrding the best practice and implementation you [could have a look here in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71244288/where-can-i-register-unit-of-work-service-in-net-6)

Hope above steps guided you accordingly to implement your requirements.