# How to define folder in visual studio for a project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I am creating a project in Visual Studio.  I have a repository folder which only gets the data from the database and I called these classes StudentRepository and interface ISomeDataRepository.  I want to keep the logic class seperate to define the business logic.  I want to know what should I call that folder and thinking what to call Student....?  The another thing is I already have a entity class student so I cannot just call that just business class as Student.

Thanks
Amir Saleem

Comment: Firstly, as your class name is `StudentRepository` as per convention the interface it would implement would convey the same name with `IStudentRepository` to redeem confusion.
In addition, business logic should be compact on repository level. You can make your repository separate from common layers introducing a service layer in between. You controller will call the service and service will communicate with the Repository finally will fetch the data from database for any request.

Comment: **Few popular architectural pattern**
You can have a look few of [`popular architectural pattern here our official document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/common-web-application-architectures#clean-architecture)
**Repository pattern Implementation**
[`You can see the Repository pattern Implementation here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71244288/where-can-i-register-unit-of-work-service-in-net-6/71249103#71249103)