# How to implement Service inherit from generic repository?

Tags: asp.net-core, oop, model-view-controller, c#-4.0, blazor-server-side

I work on `asp.net core mvc blazor` application , I have issue I can't implement service inherit from generic repository .

meaning how to inherit from IRepository to get functions below on class server names service :

Insert

Update

GetById

GetList

GetListAsync

Interface generic repository

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    

    Task<int> Count(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where);
    TEntity GetByID(object id);
    TEntity Insert(TEntity entity);
    void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate);
    Task<ICollection<TType>> Get<TType>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where, Expression<Func<TEntity, TType>> select) where TType : class;
    Task<bool> Any(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where);
    TEntity GetFirst(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where);
    TEntity Single(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where);
    Task<List<TEntity>> GetListAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where);
    List<TEntity> GetList(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where);
    Task<bool> UpdateBasedOnCondition(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where, Action<TEntity> select);
    void Save();

}
```

class that implement interface as below :

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UC.AppRepository.Core;

public class BaseRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    internal AppsRepositoryDBContext _context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public BaseRepository(AppsRepositoryDBContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        this.dbSet = _context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual TEntity GetByID(object id)
    {
        return dbSet.Find(id);
    }

    public virtual TEntity Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        var result = dbSet.AddAsync(entity).Result.Entity;
        Save();
        return result;
    }

 

  

    public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
    {
        dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
        _context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }


    public virtual async Task<bool> UpdateBasedOnCondition(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where, Action<TEntity> select)
    {
        try
        {
            var ListOfRecord = await dbSet.Where(where).ToListAsync();
            if (null != ListOfRecord && ListOfRecord.Count > 0)
            {
                ListOfRecord.ForEach(select);
                //  Save();
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
            throw;
        }

    }

    public async Task<ICollection<TType>> Get<TType>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where, Expression<Func<TEntity, TType>> select) where TType : class
    {
        if(where == null)
        {
            return await dbSet.Select(select).ToListAsync();
        }
        return await dbSet.Where(where).Select(select).ToListAsync();
    }


    public async Task<int> Count(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where)
    {
        return await dbSet.Where(where).CountAsync();
    }


  


    public async virtual Task<List<TEntity>> GetListAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where)
    {

        //  var test = dbSet.Where(where).ToList();
        return await dbSet.Where(where).ToListAsync();

    }

    public virtual List<TEntity> GetList(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where)
    {
        return dbSet.Where(where).ToList();

    }



    public async Task<bool> Any(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where)
    {
        return await dbSet.AnyAsync(where);
    }

    public TEntity GetFirst(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where)
    {
        return dbSet.FirstOrDefault(where);
    }

    public TEntity Single(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where)
    {
        return dbSet.Single(where);
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        try
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }
}
```

so I have class `ServerNameService` and class interface `IserverNamesService`
I need to implement insert,update,selectById,selectall functions for server name models
from `base repository`

```
 public class ServerNameService:IRepository
    {
// what i write here
    }


 public interface IserverNamesService:IRepository
    {
// what i write here
    }



public class ServerNames
    {
        [Key]
        public int ServerID { get; set; }
        public string Server_Name{ get; set; }
        public string Server_Type { get; set; }
        public string Operating_System { get; set; }
        public string Version { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have issue I can't implement service inherit from generic repository.I have class ServerNameService and class interface IserverNamesService I need to implement insert,update,selectById,selectall functions for server name models from base repository

Well, to directly answer your question, to implement your ServerNameService which derived from IRepository that would would be as following:

**IserverNamesService:**

```
public interface IserverNamesService : IRepository<ServerNames>
    {

    }
```

**Note:** Keep it empty because we will use of IRepository and BaseRepository in ServerNamesService class to implement its members.

**ServerNamesService:**

```
public class ServerNamesService : BaseRepository<ServerNames>, IserverNamesService
    {
        public ServerNamesService(ApplicationDbContext context) : base(context)
        {
        }


        public override ServerNames GetByID(object id)
        {
            return _context.ServerNames.Where(sn => sn.ServerID == (int)id).FirstOrDefault();

        }
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ServerNamesServiceController : ControllerBase
{

    private readonly IserverNamesService _serverNamesService;

    public ServerNamesServiceController(IserverNamesService namesService)
    {
        _serverNamesService = namesService;
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetById(object id)
    {
        var item = _serverNamesService.GetByID(id);

        if (item == null)
            return NotFound();

        return Ok(item);
    }

}
```

**Program.cs:**

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IserverNamesService, ServerNamesService>();
```

**Note:** Register your ServerNamesService class in your program.cs

**UnitOfWork Pattern Implementation:**

As long your application would continue evolving and there would be ton of service class, in that scenario, you have to introduce lot of service in your controller. But if you would like to handle those smoothly, you could use [UnitOfWork](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application#the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns) pattern which would contain all of your service together.

Interface:

```
 public interface IUnitOfWork
    {
        IserverNamesService ServerNamesService { get; }
        Task CompleteAsync();
    }
```

Implementation:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
       
        public IserverNamesService ServerNamesService { get; private set; }

       

        public UnitOfWork(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            ServerNamesService = new ServerNamesService(context);
        }
       
        public async Task CompleteAsync()
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _context.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ServerNamesServiceController : ControllerBase
    {

        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        public ServerNamesServiceController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }


        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetById(object id)
        {
            var item = _unitOfWork.ServerNamesService.GetByID(id);

            if (item == null)
                return NotFound();

            return Ok(item);
        }

    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** If you would like to know more details on [repository pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) you could [check our official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) and [working sample here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71244288/where-can-i-register-unit-of-work-service-in-net-6/71249103#71249103)

Answer (score 0):

You should pass your **Entity** as generic type to *IRepository* in *IServerNamesService*, and then inheritance  *ServerNameService* from *IServerNamesService*.

```
public interface IServerNamesService:IRepository<ServerNames>
{
    // your methods interface 
}
    
  public class ServerNameService:IServerNamesService{
         private readonly IRepository<ServerNames> _repository;
    
         public class ServerNameService(IRepository<ServerNames> repository)
         {
             _repository = repository;
         }
         //body of your methods
   }
```

Comment: thank you for reply so how to call that function inside controller  public virtual TEntity GetByID(object id)
    {
        return dbSet.Find(id);
    }